# Filter results in Microsoft Access 2010 Form using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on an Access Database where I need to display records from a table in a form as a datasheet.  I believe I have correctly written the code to perform the filtering, but am not sure how to display the records.

I know that I can perform this easier using a query, and then a form based on those results, but wish to limit this process if at all possible, to reduce the overall size of the database.  The filter will be sorting a company, and the fiscal dates.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I have thus far...

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Form_Current()
    Dim oTable As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oDataNeedsGas
    Dim dNextFiscal, dThisFiscal
    Dim iGas


'Fiscal Year turnover date, use DateValue(dNextFiscal) comparison.
    dNextFiscal = "10/1/" & Year(Date)
    dThisFiscal = "10/1/" & Year(Date) - 1

    'For Annual training by year comparison.
    'Year(DateValue(oTable!randomdate)) >= Year(Date)

Set oTable = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_main", dbOpenDynaset)    
    iGas = 0

Do Until oTable.EOF = True
    If (Year(DateValue(oTable![GasDate])) >= Year(Date) And oTable![Platoon] = "Data") Then
        `What do I do here?!!?
        iGas = iGas + 1
    End If
msgbox iGas

oTable.MoveNext

Loop  

End Sub
```

I know the filtering works, because I have it count the matched records, then display in a message box, but I want to be able to display the matched records.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make the RecordSource on your Datasheet from blank and then have this code run when the form loads:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sSQL as String
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Main "
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE Year(DateValue(GasDate)) >= Year(Date) "
    sSQL = sSQL & " AND Platoon = 'Data'"
    Me.RecordSource = sSQL
    MsgBox "RecordCount: " & Me.RecordCount
End Sub
```

I generally use the Form's RecordSource and the Forms Filter and FilterOn properties. You can always load the form showing all records and then filter down to what you want to see.

I didn't understand this line in your question:
*"...but wish to limit this process if at all possible, to reduce the overall size of the database."*

Are you trying to increase performance? Are you worried about storing too much data and the tables getting too large? That part of your question just isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.  In the past I have built a query separating the information, then made a form to display what is in the query.  Unfortunately, they want me to make this usable by more than just me.  Our network drive is severly limited on space; so I am attempting to reduce the size of the database to prevent it from crowding the share drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Subform's `Recordset` property to oTable. Make the recordset a property of the main form though, as shown in the following code, so that you can release this reference when the form closes.

```
Option Compare Database
Private oTable As Object

Private Sub Command2_Click()

    Set oTable = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_main", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set Me.sbfName.Form.Recordset = oTable
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    If Not oTable Is Nothing Then
        Set oTable = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

For your specific example you would `OpenRecordset` based on a SQL statement that includes your date-criteria. I haven't tested whether this will be updateable, as it is for a Table. (I am getting the impression that it will not be updateable.)

It *is possible* to do this but I'm not suggesting it is a recommended approach. It is far easier to use the `RecordSource` property, filtering its records.

I want to emphasise that I **would not** use the `Recordset` of the subform. Use the `RecordSource`. You can set it to a SQL statement and/or filter records. Using the `Recordset` property is problematic (and unnecessary).